# Simple JavaScript encryption function

Tags: javascript

I have a function which has to change characters from one array to the characters from another. It is kind of simple encryption. I have:

```
var plainArray = ['A','B','C',...,'Z'];
var cipherArray = ['a','b','c',...,'z'];
function rotateToPosition(signalCharacter, indexCharacter, plainAlphabet, cipherAlphabet)
```

already working. 
Now I have to write a function which will change given word into encrypted word.

```
function encrypt(plainText, signalCharacter, indexCharacter, plainAlphabet, cipherAlphabet)
{
   var encryptedString = signalCharacter;
   //i is what will hold the results of the encrpytion until it can be appended to encryptedString
   var i;
   // rotate array to signal character position
   var rotateArray = rotateToPosition(signalCharacter, indexCharacter, plainAlphabet, cipherAlphabet);
   for (var count = 0; count < plainText.length; count++)
   {
       plainAlphabet = plainText.charAt(count);
       i = cipherAlphabet[plainAlphabet];
       encryptedString = encryptedString + rotateArray[i];
   }

   return encryptedString;
}
```

This function returns signal character and then a string of errors. Do you know what is wrong?

Comment: What are the errors?

Comment: What is `rotateToPosition` function?

Comment: What are you using this for? I ask this because having your encryption algorithm in JS for all to see, isn't very secure. You would be better off having the encryption take place on the server.

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting `plainAlphabet` with one character, thus discarding the alphabet. I guess that's not what you want.

However, you only posted the signature of `rotateToPosition` and not the actual code of it, so I cannot test my solution.

```
function encrypt(plainText, signalCharacter, indexCharacter, plainAlphabet, cipherAlphabet) {
   var encryptedString = signalCharacter;
   //i is what will hold the results of the encrpytion until it can be appended to encryptedString
   var i;
   // rotate array to signal character position
   var rotateArray = rotateToPosition(signalCharacter, indexCharacter, plainAlphabet, cipherAlphabet);
   for (var count = 0; count < plainText.length; count++)
   {
       var plainLetter = plainText.charAt(count);
       i = cipherAlphabet[plainLetter];
       encryptedString = encryptedString + rotateArray[i];
   }

   return encryptedString;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I also think so. In JS most non-simple vars are by reference.